# Accepting only Valid Time

Tags: java, validation, parsing, time, input

Alright so in Java I want to ask the user for a time in 24-hour format. I have managed to leverage `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` to tell it what format the time is being entered in and then to interpret that accordingly, throwing an exception if it does not follow that format. Here is what I have:

```
DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

try {
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();
    Date theDate = fmt.parse(input);
    System.out.println(theDate.toString());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Incorrect format!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If I type in a word, it indeed throws an exception. However, if I type in something like `234234:2342342` it actually goes and does the math to figure out how many days those hours and minutes equate to, then outputs the actual date. For example, given input:

```
input: 23423423:232323
output: Fri Jul 29 07:03:00 PDT 4642
```

I am wondering if there is a way to treat this as an exception. So I want to only accept what the formatters specify (H 0-23 and m 0-59), and if it does not fall within these boundaries, throw an exception or have some way of knowing. What I would like to know is if there is a way to do this within the formatter classes I am using, or if it should be done using the Scanner class (how?), or if I have to write the parsing and validation code myself. Am I approaching this completely wrong? I am currently just trying out the possibilities, so if there is a better way please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out, using `DateFormat`'s [`setLenient`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) method.

```
fmt.setLenient(false);
```

Now typing in anything that doesn't fit the format (hour = 0 to 23 and minute = 0 to 59) it throws an exception :)

Comment: I think you're about to get a Self-Learner badge :)